# Rsync copy error

Tags: rsync

I am trying to copy a directory from a remote machine's root directory to this directory /root/data_directory_backup_from_backup02 in a local machine.
I spent some time to fix this but no luck. Am I making any mistakes regarding this destination path?

```
/usr/bin/rsync -avz -e  ssh root@x.x.x.x:/backups/ /root/data_directory_backup_from_backup02
```

But I get the message.Could someone please help me why is so?

`/usr/bin/rsync -avz -e  ssh root@x.x.x.x:/backups/ /root/data_directory_backup_from_backup02 > /var/tmp/rsync_latest_run 2>&1`

> Unexpected local arg: /root/data_directory_backup_from_backup02
>   If arg is a remote file/dir, prefix it with a colon (:).
>   rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1228) [Receiver=3.0.9]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rsync incorporates ssh.  I'm pretty sure something like:

`rsync -avz root@x.x.x.x:/backups/ /root/data_directory_backup_from_backup02`

... will work just fine.

Comment: nope not working bringing error

Comment: Read again.  I removed the who `-e ssh` thing.

Comment: before I posted i tried this and now again tried gives me this error ´Unexpected local arg: /root/data_directory_backup_from_backup02
If arg is a remote file/dir, prefix it with a colon (:).
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1228) [Receiver=3.0.9]´

Comment: Can you give me the output of:  `if [ -d /root/data_directory_backup_from_backup02 ]; then echo OK ; else echo NOK ; fi`

Comment: The output is OK

Comment: It was just a check to see whether the directory `/root/data_directory_backup_from_backup02` actually existed.  It does.  I'll see if I can find anything else, but I tried out the command (with adapted paths) on my environment, and there it works... :-/

Comment: yes it does work now. The problem lied here  " > /var/tmp/rsync_latest_run 2>&1 " .Thanks for quick reply.